# C# Cannot join main thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, join, program-entry-point

I have very simple code which behavior I cannot understand.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Get reference to main thread
        Thread mainThread = Thread.CurrentThread;

        // Start second thread
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Working...");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            Console.WriteLine("Work finished. Waiting for main thread to end...");
            mainThread.Join();        // Obviously this join cannot pass

            Console.WriteLine("This message never prints. Why???");
        }).Start();

        Thread.Sleep(300);
        Console.WriteLine("Main thread ended");
    }
}
```

Output of this never-ending program is:

```
Working...
Main thread ended
Work finished. Waiting for main thread to end...
```

Why the threads' code get stuck on the `Join()` method call? By other print outs can be find out, that already before `Join()` call, the property`IsAlive`  of `mainThread` is set to false and the `ThreadState` is `Background, Stopped, WaitSleepJoin`. Also removing sleeps doesn't make any difference.

What's the reasoning for this behavior? What mystery is under the hood of `Join()` method and execution of `Main` method?

Comment: main thread termination usually coincides with *process* termination. I'm guessing that's doing things to your code that you don't want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Join()` works as you expect it to, the issue here is with the assumption that the thread running `Main()` terminates when `Main()` returns, which is not always the case.

Your `Main()` method is called by the .NET framework, and when the method returns, there is additional code executed by the framework before the main thread (and hence the process) exits. Specifically, one of the things the framework does as part of the post-Main code is wait for all foreground threads to exit.

This essentially results in a classic deadlock situation - the main thread is waiting for your worker thread to exit, and your worker thread is waiting for the main thread to exit.

Of course, if you make your worker thread a background thread, (by setting `IsBackground = true` before starting it) then the post-Main code won't wait for it to exit, eliminating the deadlock. However your `Join()` will *still* never return because when the main thread does exit, the process also exits.

For more details on the framework internals that run before and after `Main()`, you can take a look at the .NET Core codebase on GitHub. The overall method that runs `Main()` is [`Assembly::ExecuteMainMethod`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/a7f6a9d7a1302c355bbf87aba81143e586bdfad8/src/vm/assembly.cpp#L1763), and the code that runs *after* `Main()` returns is [`Assembly::RunMainPost`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/a7f6a9d7a1302c355bbf87aba81143e586bdfad8/src/vm/assembly.cpp#L1735).

Comment: Yeah, that's better than my answer.  +1 for linking the source.  I was just about to do that myself.

Comment: That's very nice explanation. I'm also very happy for the source code linked which supports the statement. I didn't know exactly where to look for this piece of code.

Comment: Just the mainThread state and isAlive property value is confusing. Is there a reason for this too?